# How to perform dynamic URL rewrite...in code

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting, coldfusion

I am being asked if I can setup a way to - on the fly - dynamically do a URL rewrite.

My experience with URL rewriting has been primarily using essentially static web.config files where I knew ahead of time what the conditions were I was supporting.  But in this case, I'm working with a partner who is sending me data about their clients and when a user of my site gets sent to one of those pages, they'd like me to rewrite the URL so that it looks like their client's URL and not mine.

Example:  the search my site for Jim's auto shop, when I display my (their) content about Jim's auto shop, the URL wouldn't appear to be on my site, it would show "www.JimsAutoShop.com" when it's really on "wwww.mysite.com/JimsAutoShop"

I suppose every time our partner pushes we data where this is needed, I could rewrite the web.config file adding a section for that case, but I really don't know that that's a good idea.  is there a way to essentially do this dynamically via code, where when I query my db from a search and see I need to mask the URL, I could do that?

Tech wise, i do not have access to IIS, I'm on a shared server running IIS and my primary application stack is Coldfusion10.   Thanks

Comment: If you had access to IIS, you can start a site called "JimsAutoShop.com" and it's root would be the directory [...]/mysites.com/wwwroot/JimsAutoShop/. Since you're on a shared server I don't think this is possible, but you can still ask the hosting provider.

Comment: Thanks Jules.  Well since there could be hundred of these domains that they want to mask, I don't think it's doable even if the host would give me that level of ability.  I'm just going to tell them no, we can't accomplish their request

Comment: That's probably for the better. You'd get flagged by SE's for duplicate content anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. By the time your server side language gets the code, everything has been processed on the web server. There is nothing to rewrite. You could technically do this with Javascript but it would just be visually, it wouldn't actually be changing the URL. (Not sure you could visually change the domain, but I don't see why not. I've done it before with other parts of the URL). Here is how you would do that essentially: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

If this needs to be done though, the web.config route is the way to go. I had an application where when data was updated using certain forms in the app, I would grab the web.config and edit one of the rewrite maps.

But I'm not so sure that is what you need. If you want the domain www.JimsAutoShop.com to just pull files form your server, just edit the DNS to point to your server. Rewriting/Redirecting isn't needed. That is how sites are supposed to work.

Comment: Thanks Leeish.  In this case, there could be thousands of potential domains they want my content show as, so it's not real practical to actually host the information there.  I'm not 100% sure why they see this as an advantage but they asked so I thought I'd ask here in case someone knew of a way i hadn't thought of.  I'm just very hesitant to be routinely editing the web.config file given a small mishap with that breaks most of my site.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand exactly but you can't visit bobssite.com and have it show up as Facebook.com. It just doesn't work that way.

Comment: Right.  I'm not 100% sure why this feature was important too them.  I suppose since "jim" would be their customer, they wanted to try and make the content seem like it was "jims" but I'm not going to worry about it.  Thanks All